# WSGIPassAuthorization On directive in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I am get issue with set  WSGIPassAuthorization On directive in .htaccess.

any one can suggest how to add this variable to .htaccess ?

thank all so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually state what the specific error you get is when you try.

Has your Apache even been configured to allow use of .htaccess files?

Has your Apache even been configured to allow FileInfo overrides in .htaccess files?

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Both would be required for WSGIPassAuthorization to work in a .htaccess file.

So please tell us what the error is you get in the browser and in the Apache error logs.

Indicate whether you have taken the steps above.

Comment: hi,
this is configure in godaddy, and I cant find log file for apache configure.
I cant manage apache configure so, I see that i need to custom .htaccess file.
Do you have any suggestion about that ?